# How to split long line in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a line in my Django template that is too long:

```
 {% for some_item, some_another_item, again_some_another_item_with_long_name in items %}
```

Is there a way to split it so that it looks nicer in the source code?

Using `\` or just splitting doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think this is possible - I think your only options are to use shorter names, or perhaps write a custom template tag.

Comment: Just by curiousness, what is the type of your `items` variable for wanting to select 3 variables inside it ?

Comment: You may want to use items not as a list of tuples, but list of dictionaries:
{% for item in items %}
{{ item.some }} {{ item.some_another }} {{ item.some_another_long }}
{% endfor %}
It will be shorter. Don't think it's possible to split either

Comment: Yes, it was obvious solution for that particular problem. But I'd want to have more general solution...

Comment: I don't think it's problem at all) Yes it looks ugly when the line is too long. But would it be less ugly if it would be splited?

Answer (score 12):

If you really want to keep those nasty long names, what I would do is:

```
{% for a, b, c in items %}
    {% with a as some_item %}
    {% with b as some_another_item %}
    {% with c as again_some_another_item_with_long_name %}
        bla bla bla ..
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's possible workaround. But I prefered to rewrite code using list of dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'word wrap' or 'soft wraps' feature of your text editor.
In the PyCharm if you search by `soft` you will see:

[image]