# django template coding style line break for a long line of code

Tags: django, templates

I have very long code in one line, like this

```
{% for student_id, name, gender, family_description, grade, class, date in report_info %}
```

Can I break that into two lines using slash or other symbol?

Comment: you can't do that.
a workaround 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077609/how-to-split-long-line-in-django-template

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I find myself trying to coerce Django's templating system to short-cut long lines of code like this, it's almost always a red-flag for me to rethink my data structure.

Perhaps you can consider changing `report_info` so that each item in `report_info` is actually a dict, or a class.

```
report_info = [
    {"student_id": id, "name": name, "gender": gender, ...},
    ...
]
```

And then in your template, the iteration is simple, and not long:

```
{% for report_item in report_info %}
    {{ report_item.student_id }}
    {{ report_item.name }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```